# Question tag for a sentence

Tags: tag-questions

What will be the question tags for the following two sentences

> I have a correct answer.
>
> She had another answer.

According to me it should be

> 1. Don't I?
> 2. Didn't she?

Respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag questions uses the auxiliary verb.  When the sentence uses "have" as a main verb then the tag would use "do" as the auxiliary.  That is the case here.  The tag questions are "don't I" and "didn't she"

You can check by thinking what the full question would be

> Do I have a correct answer?

This uses "do" so the tag uses "don't".

In some dialects, the question can be "Have I correct answer" so the tag could also be "haven't I" in those dialects.